# Making a 1 time payment to IRS

Tags: united-states, taxes

When making a 1-time tax payment to the IRS, because of a 1-time cash windfall, how does that factor into my taxes during tax time? Do I get a form or receipt of the 1-time payment that I enter somewhere on my 1040?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sending in the money yourself, or is the a casino, broker, or some other organization withholding the money and sending it to the IRS?

Comment: im making the payment directly to the IRS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just talked to an IRS person over the phone. They informed me that you don't get a receipt or anything when making a direct IRS payment, beyond a confirmation number. But I do enter the amount paid on line 65 of my 1040 Federal Tax Return form when I do my end of the year taxes.

Comment: Since you got your answer from the IRS directly, it seems your answer is as definitive as it gets. Feel free to accept your own answer with the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

You *do* get an email confirmation if you want one; but you don't need it.

You simply list the payment on your tax filing, and it will be fine - when paying, you specify the SSN the payment relates too, and that is sufficient connection.

Just make sure to spell your SSN correctly when paying.